# Using IRF7821PbF mosfet without a gate driver

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, powermosfet

I have extracted some information from the [datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf7821pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535608d7f31d06) of the IRF7821PbF and would like some confirmation on it.

1. I calculated that if I have a 6A load, it only dissipates 0.32W and gets only 16° warmer than ambient? Is this correct? It seems too good to me.
2. I calculated that if my microcontroller (3.3 V) can source 4 mA of current to drive the gate, I am limited to about 500 Hz switching speed if I assume about 8 nC of total gate charge.
3. With 3.3V at the gate, I can easily drive my 6A load.

Is the above all correct? If not please correct me.

Comment: I wouldn't drive this FET with 3.3 V. It's only rated for drive voltages of 4.5 V and 10 V, and if you look at figure 12 of the [datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf7821pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535608d7f31d06), the on resistance at 3.3 V is many times greater than either of those. You might have a hard time finding FETs with really low on resistance at 3.3 V; I would at least drive it through a cheap gate driver (or even just a TTL inverter) powered by 5 V or more.

Comment: dangit, you are right. I missed that!

Comment: what would you consider a cheap gate driver? I cannot find anything below $1 at german sellers, thats quite expensive..

Comment: Always be sure to check that your FET has some sort of usable on resistance at the voltage you intend to drive the gate to! The IRL series from IR/Infineon are "logic-level" FETs, intended to be driven by logic signals; usually 5 V but some have ratings for lower voltages. The IRL6342, for instance, lists typical on resistance of 15 mΩ at 2.5 V drive, so perhaps that's worth looking into.

Comment: Since I don't know what's available to you, I would suggest looking into just using a TTL inverter. You can get those quite cheaply--some in tiny packages like SOT-23-5--from various manufacturers. TTL (or CMOS with TTL-level inputs, like the 74HCT series) is handy for this sort of thing, because regardless of the voltage powering the logic, the input high level is anything more than about a volt, so you can use it to shift voltage levels quite cheaply. Makes a decent gate driver if you don't need anything with amps of drive strength.

Comment: thats a great idea, I will look into it! sadly the IRL6342 is not available currently

Comment: could you give a example TTL inverter? I found the 74HC04, would that work? and am I assuming correctly that I would connect VCC of the ttl inverter to 5V and drive the inputs with the 3.3V from my uC?

Comment: does M74HC04 + SI4178DY-GE3 sound good?

Comment: or the IRLR 120N

Comment: ok, after some search, the IRLR8256PBF is my favourite..

Comment: A 74HC part won't work, you'd need 74HCT to have compatible input levels.

Comment: oh yes ofcourse. thanks for your help!

Comment: @Hearth can I ask you one more thing? could I use an OR gate instead of a NOT and just fix one of the inputs to ground? that way my logic wouldnt be inverted..

Comment: Yes, any TTL-compatible logic chip would work. An inverter is just the simplest. I would recommend looking at the single-gate ones in SOT-23-5 or SC-70-5 for the small footprint.

Comment: thanks! as I have 6 mosfets, I will use the so14 package with 6 inverters. I think I will continue to use inverters though because the inversion is not really a problem and OR gates are bigger (extra inputs). also, Im using another 47HCT in paralell to switch status LEDs for the mosfets, as that seemed to be the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These were comments, but I turned it into an answer because it really is an answer to the question. I'll edit this into a better format when I get back from work tonight, if I have some time.

---

I wouldn't drive this FET with 3.3 V. It's only rated for drive voltages of 4.5 V and 10 V, and if you look at figure 12 of the datasheet, the on resistance at 3.3 V is many times greater than either of those. You might have a hard time finding FETs with really low on resistance at 3.3 V; I would at least drive it through a cheap gate driver (or even just a TTL inverter) powered by 5 V or more.

---

Always be sure to check that your FET has some sort of usable on resistance at the voltage you intend to drive the gate to! The IRL series from IR/Infineon are "logic-level" FETs, intended to be driven by logic signals; usually 5 V but some have ratings for lower voltages. The IRL6342, for instance, lists typical on resistance of 15 mΩ at 2.5 V drive, so perhaps that's worth looking into.

---

Since I don't know what's available to you, I would suggest looking into just using a TTL inverter. You can get those quite cheaply--some in tiny packages like SOT-23-5--from various manufacturers. TTL (or CMOS with TTL-level inputs, like the 74HCT series) is handy for this sort of thing, because regardless of the voltage powering the logic, the input high level is anything more than about a volt, so you can use it to shift voltage levels quite cheaply. Makes a decent gate driver if you don't need anything with amps of drive strength.